# Typescript: dynamically calculated field on object initialization

Tags: typescript, class, initialization, computed-properties, computed-field

I'm building a design system in Typescript and I would like to have fields for lighter/darker color to be calculated dynamically based on the main (required) color. The setup is following:

```
export default class Color {
  main: string = "#000000"; //required color
  light?: string = calculateLight(this.main);
  dark?: string = calculateDark(this.main);
}
```

Color object is then used in Palette type:

```
type ColorTypes = "primary" | "accent"; //I need this to restrict available values later in components' props

type Palette = {
  [key in ColorTypes]: Color; //created based on ColorTypes for easier code updates
};
export default Palette;
```

Now i would like to initialize Theme using Palette with curly braces:

```
export const theme: ITheme = {
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#323130",
    },
    accent: {
      main: "#0078d4",
    },
  }
};
```

But `light` and `dark` fields remain undefined.

Is there any way to have it done automatically?
Or the only way to do it is using a helper function like `createTheme` which would iterate through each `Color` in `Palette` and execute a constructor or function?

Comment: Yes, you will need a helper function to iterate over the palette and assign missing colors. Types are removed after transpilation and there is no way to say to typescript "if I write `const color: Color = {main: '#fff'}` please add fields `light` and `dark` automatically"

Comment: Thank you! I just noticed that in a curly-braces-way I could also initialize ```Color``` object directly, e.g.: ```primary: new Color("#112233")```. Do you think helper function would be of any benefit in this case then?

Comment: Well, depends on your case, but I don't think so. The only improvement you could do is to accept and object in the constructor like `new Color({main: '#112233'})` so that it's more clear, otherwise do whatever works for you